# outlook addin goes straight to inactive application addins

Tags: outlook, windows-installer

My Outlook addin MSI installs the addin (It is listed in Add\Remove programs) but sends it straight to  inactive application addins.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the LoadBehavior key value for your plugin.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\%your add in%\LoadBehavior
```

If you see the registry hive for you add-in - it's most likely to be installed correctly.
The LoadBehavior value should be 3 *before* you start Outlook. If it's not, set it to 3.
If it goes to 2 when you start Outlook - it is definitely trying to run it, so it's good news in a way.

You will need to do some diagnostics there - try instantiating your add-in from vbs

```
set c = CreateObject("EnthusiasticDeveloper.OutlookAddIn")
```

This should give you no errors.
If it doesn't and the object is instantiated - you need to put diagnostics in your add-in.
It is being called by Outlook and your most likely to get enough control to instantiate log4net.

HTH

Answer (score 4):

It seems the MS Outlook started evaluating the add-ins that directly affect product overall performance and set them as inactive. I found this article that indicates the windows registry entry for DisabledItems (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DisabledItems). It is much likely to your add-in be listed on this folder. Backup the related entry before removing it.

See detailed information on this accessing:
http://www.outlook-apps.com/inactive-outlook-add-ins/

Cheers,
Vieira

Answer (score 2):

This probably happens because the load behavior is not set correctly. This article can help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/ff937654.aspx#Create

Comment: I have followed this step-by-step to the letter and my load behavior is set to 3 as required. It still installs the addin to inactive.

Comment: Is the addin working correctly if you place the file manually in a folder and also manually create the registry entries, without using a setup package?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Do you know a good step by step I can follow?